# pandas how to batch process all the values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Pandas DataFrame` and all the value are `str`s, I want to get the first 4 characters of every value. And I wonder are there any built-in functions that can do this.

I can do this by using for loop:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=my_columns)
>>> for values in df.iteritems():
        for value in values[1].tolist():
            print value[0:4]
```

But, that's hard to read and not pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) with a lambda that calls the vectorise [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods to slice your strings:

```
In [136]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asdas','asdasdsadas','123124'],'b':['554653645','546456453634','uyiyasdhnfjnas']})
df

Out[136]:
             a               b
0        asdas       554653645
1  asdasdsadas    546456453634
2       123124  uyiyasdhnfjnas

In [138]:    
df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:4])

Out[138]:
      a     b
0  asda  5546
1  asda  5464
2  1231  uyiy
```